# Apache ActiveMQ wiretap using Apache Camel

Tags: java, python, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to do event scouring with Apache Camel.
For messaging bus I am using ActiveMQ.

### Use cases

I want to audit each messages that are pushed to ActiveMQ using MongoDB as persistent storage. I have tried with mirrored queues in ActiveMQ. This pushes the message to a topic with the same name as queue.
But I have to implement worker based (load balancing) approach. This is not possible with topic (message duplication not allowed).
So I planned to use ActiveMQ with Camel by using the wiretap pattern.

### Desired output:

Can I pull the message from wiretap destination and insert it into MongoDB or is there a way that can Camel directly insert it into MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to tackle this on the broker side is with [Composite Destinations](https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations).  You can instruct the broker to forward messages sent to a Queue on to another Queue.  Some care needs to be taken when doing this as by default this only happens when the Queue exists (static configuration of destinations can get round this).  There is an option to always forward and you also have the option of applying selectors to reduce what gets sent.  The thing to keep in mind is that unless you have something periodically purging the audit queue you will eventually run out of space.

You can configure the forwarding as follows:

```
<compositeQueue name="myQueue" forwardOnly="false">   
  <forwardTo>
    <queue physicalName="myAuditQueue" />
  </forwardTo>
</compositeQueue>
```

Comment: Does the composite queue name support wildcard(*, .) so that i can able send all the queues message to  `physicalName`

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: I tried with (*) for routing all the queue data to a specific queue(event_store). Its not working. Thanks for your valuable time @tim Bish